# JScrollPane en JPanel con BoxLayout no funciona correctamente

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con JavaMail y actualmente el programa crea un JPanel por cada correo electronico recibido y lo pone en una ventana superior que usa el BoxLayout a la vez el padre de el JPanel es un JScrollPane.

Os pongo un ejemplo de la estructura.

```
ventanaPartes - JPanel
   ->...
   ->contenedorPartes - JScrollPane
      ->partes - JPanel - Layout(BoxLayout)
        ->JPanel por cada correo.
```

El problema es que tengo ,por ejemplo, 8 correos y el BoxLayout me pone los 8 correos en el JPanel sin respetar los bounds de el JPanel de el correo electronico y hace caso omiso a el JScrollPane, os adjunto una imagen
[image: Ejemplo Grafico de el problema]

He estado intentando de varias formas para poden hacer que el JScrollPane actue como debe, pero sin efecto, paso codigo:

```
VentanaPartes = new JPanel();
Ventana.add(VentanaPartes);
VentanaPartes.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
VentanaPartes.setLayout(null);

contenedorPartes = new JPanel();
contenedorPartes.setBounds(0, 0, 1500, 8000);
contenedorPartes.setBackground(Color.blue);
contenedorPartes.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contenedorPartes, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

partes = new JScrollPane();
partes.setBounds(0, 135, 1500, 800);
partes.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
partes.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
partes.add(contenedorPartes);
partes.setViewportView(contenedorPartes);
VentanaPartes.add(partes);
```

Aqui esta el codigo de el metodo que crea los JPanels.

```
    public void emailAComponente(String asunto, String contenido) {

    log.info("Creando componentes para el mensaje: " + asunto);

    //Iniciamos una instancia para poder acceder a la ventana pertinente
    JPanel formularios = App.getControlador().getInicio().getContenedorPartes();


    //Configuramos el panel que se va a crear
    JPanel panel = new BorderJPanel(30,Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //El JPanel deberia crearse con estas medidas, pero el BoxLayout las ignora
    panel.setBounds(0,0, 500, 800);


    //Creamos la etiqueta de el asunto
    JLabel lblAsunto = new JLabel(asunto);
    lblAsunto.setBounds(20, 20, 250, 12);
    lblAsunto.setFont(new Font("Doppio One", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblAsunto.setVisible(true);

    //Creamos la etiqueta con lo que contiene el mensaje
    JTextArea lblContenedor = new JTextArea(contenido);
    lblContenedor.setBounds(20, 50, 500, 70);
    lblContenedor.setFont(new Font("Doppio One", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    lblContenedor.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(lblAsunto);
    panel.add(lblContenedor);
    panel.paintComponents(panel.getGraphics());
    panel.setVisible(true);

    formularios.add(panel);

}
```

Aqui va mi primera pregunta, si pongo los bounds del JPanel en una cantidad desmesurada como esta ahora de 8000px en el eje vertical, el JScrollPane deberia automaticamente actuar para poder deslizarse por ese panel?

Segunda pregunta, Si creo el JPanel con setBounds(0,0,1000,8000)
porque el BoxLayout actua como si fueran las medidas de el JScrollPane? (0,0,1500, 800)

Alguna idea para que funcione correctamente? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final tras 3 dias se investigacion, he logrado saber porque no estaba funcionando, parece ser que para que vaya bien el JScrollPane hay que poner lo siguiente:

```
        contenedor = new JPanel();
    contenedor.setLayout(null);ventanaSuperior.setLocation(0, 65);
    ventanaSuperior.setSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
    ventanaSuperior.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1700, 6000));
    ventanaSuperior.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    ventanaSuperior.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1800, 6000));
```

Con #setBounds(int,int, int,int) no funcionaria de la misma manera, esta es la forma de forzar a que el JScrollPane desplegue sus barras verticales o laterales